# Calculate diff. between two times given that we have two different strings for time and date

Tags: java, date, time

I have time data split in two strings - one string for date, and one for time.
I want to calculate the diff. of such two times in Java.
e.g.

- time 1:"26/02/2011" and "11:00 AM"
- time 2:"27/02/2011" and "12:15 AM"

Difference would be like 13 hours 15 minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String str_date1 = "26/02/2011";
String str_time1 = "11:00 AM";

String str_date2 = "27/02/2011";
String str_time2 = "12:15 AM" ;

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
Date date1 = formatter.parse(str_date1 + " " + str_time1);
Date date2 = formatter.parse(str_date2 + " " + str_time2);

// Get msec from each, and subtract.
long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

System.out.println("Difference In Days: " + (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
```

Obs: This is only valid as an aproximation. See [Losing Time on the Garden Path](http://www.xmission.com/~goodhill/dates/deltaDates.html).)

Comment: Your program gives exception: `Unparseable date: "26/02/2011 11:00 AM"`. This is because you use `-` in formatter and `/` in date string.

Comment: @Harry Oh. I fixed the SimpleDateFormat string. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
try {
    String date1 = "26/02/2011";
    String time1 = "11:00 AM";
    String date2 = "27/02/2011";
    String time2 = "12:15 AM";

    String format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

    Date dateObj1 = sdf.parse(date1 + " " + time1);
    Date dateObj2 = sdf.parse(date2 + " " + time2);
    System.out.println(dateObj1);
    System.out.println(dateObj2);

    long diff = dateObj2.getTime() - dateObj1.getTime();
    double diffInHours = diff / ((double) 1000 * 60 * 60);
    System.out.println(diffInHours);
    System.out.println("Hours " + (int)diffInHours);
    System.out.println("Minutes " + (diffInHours - (int)diffInHours)*60 );

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

output

```
Sat Feb 26 11:00:00 EST 2011
Sun Feb 27 00:15:00 EST 2011
13.25
Hours 13
Minutes 15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), you can use it to parse your strings with the parse(String source) method and the you can easily manipulate the two Dates object to obtain what you want.

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
Date date1 = df.parse(string1);
Date date2 = df.parse(string2);
long difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
Date myDate = new Date(difference);
```

The to show the Date :

```
String diff = df.format(myDate);
```

Comment: DateFormat.parse() is not static, you need some concrete DateFormat instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the strings to `java.util.Date` objects (using `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` for instance). Then you can use `Date.getTime()` for each of the two Date instances that you parsed and compute the difference in milliseconds or make use of a `java.util.Calendar` or the joda time API for advanced computations.

Comment: it is fine but how can i make a single date object with two strings?

Comment: You can't. You'll end up with two Date objects that you will than compare. Let me edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: i know that i have to compare two different objects but i am asking how to put time and date in a single object?

Comment: You will need to concatenate those two strings and use a format pattern like this: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`. Have a look at the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc. tiagoinu's answer bellow contains a concrete example of this.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(
    ZonedDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.parse( "26/02/2011" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ) ,
        LocalTime.parse( "11:00 AM" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" ) ) ,
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    )
    ,
    ZonedDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.parse( "27/02/2011" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ) ,
        LocalTime.parse( "12:15 AM" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" ) ) ,
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
    )
).toString()
```

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/vFvq3F).

## Time zone

The Question and the other Answers all ignore the crucial issue of time zone. You cannot calculate elapsed time between two date-time strings without knowing the intended time zone. For example, in places with Daylight Saving Time (DST), on the night of the cut-over, a day may be 23 hours long or 25 hours long rather than 24 hours long.

## java.time

The modern way to do date-time work is with the java.time classes. These supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

### `Local…`

First parse the input strings. These lack any indication of time zone, so we parse them as `Local…` types.

Define a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) to match your string inputs. By the way, in the future, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when serializing date-time values to text.

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "26/02/2011" , df ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2011-02-2011

```
DateTimeFormatter tf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "11:00 AM" , tf ) ;
```

> lt.toString(): 11:00:00

### `ZoneId`

You need to know the time zone intended by your business scenario. I will arbitrarily choose one.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply the zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
```

> zdtStart.toString(): 2011-02-26T11:00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

### `Duration`

Do the same to get a `zdtStop`. Calculate the elapsed time as a span of time not attached to the timeline, in a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop );
```

Call `toString` to generate a String in [standard ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning while the `T` separates the two portions.

```
String output = d.toString();
```

> d.toString(): PT13H15M

In Java 9 and later, call the `to…Part` methods to access each component.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: The statement "The Question and the other Answers all ignore the crucial issue of time zone" is not quite true. The answer of @Bala R does take the system timezone into account (implicitly) and can correctly display the result on quasi UTC-timeline in hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

you can calculate days,hours and minutes

```
public class TimeUtils {

public static final String HOURS = "hours";
public static final String MINUTES = "minutes";
public static final String DAYS = "days";

 public static int findTheNumberBetween(String type, Date day1, Date day2) {

    long diff = day2.getTime() - day1.getTime();
    switch (type) {
        case DAYS:
            return (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        case HOURS:
            return (int) TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        case MINUTES:
            return (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

and the use it like

```
  Date day1= TimeUtils.getDateTime("2016-12-08 02:06:14");
    Date day2 = TimeUtils.getDateTime("2016-12-08 02:10:14");

    Log.d(TAG, "The difference: "+TimeUtils.findTheNumberBetween(TimeUtils.MINUTES,day1,day2));
```